# Updated ComplexObject values AfterSaveEntities: missing from server to client

Tags: breeze

I am calculating some values in the `AfterSaveEntities` method on the server using Breeze `EFContextProvider`. I am doing this for several different entity types.

After I calculate the new values, I save them to the datastore (using a new datacontext as specified in other SO questions).

I also update the entities in the saveMap with these new scalar values. These values are just integer properties that make up a ComplexObject that is a property of the entity being saved.

Everything works great. I can see just before my SaveChanges API function returns to client, that the properties are my ComplexObject are all correct.

Now, for most of my entity types, when the saveResult hits the client, everything is as expected. EXCEPT...for one of my entity types.

For this problem entity, the properties of the ComplexObject are not getting updated. If I look at the client-side `complexAspect.originalValues` property of the ComplexObject, the originalValues are the values I'm expecting to be the actual values the object...the same values that it had just before it left the server in the SaveChanges result.

I'm wondering if the answer is with adjusting `entityInfo.OriginalValuesMap` in the AfterSaveEntities function. But it didn't seem to make a different. I wonder if working with Complex Objects requires a different syntax when adjusting the OriginalValuesMap.

---

**EDIT:** I discovered that this unexpected behavior happens only when I create a new EntityInfo and add it to the SaveMap Dictionary in AfterSaveEntities.

The new entities that I create via `CreateEntityInfo(entity, Breeze.ContexProvider.EntityState.Unchanged)` are added to the saveMap with proper Type as the key.

Ironically, these extra entities all have the properties on their complex objects show up fine on client side. But as soon as I add more entities to the saveMap is when my original entity (that is already in the saveMap) starts messing up.

I hope I made my problem clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for anyone else with this problem...

The problem goes back to having 2 datacontexts...I needed a 2nd one to load related entities to do calculations for business logic.

I was adding entities from my 2nd context back into the SaveMap...I fixed this by instead loading those entities from the original breeze context and saving THOSE into the SaveMap.

```
Protected Overrides Sub AfterSaveEntities(saveMap As Dictionary(Of Type, List(Of EntityInfo)), keyMappings As List(Of KeyMapping))
        Dim context2 = New Data.Db(EntityConnection)
        context2.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = False
        context2.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False


        Dim newEntitiesMap As New Dictionary(Of Type, EntityInfo)
        For Each entType In saveMap
            Select Case entType.Key.Name
                Case "Registration"
                    For Each ent In entType.Value
                        Dim registration = DirectCast(ent.Entity, Registration)
                        registration.Stats = GenerateRegistrationStats(context2, registration.Id)
                    Next
                Case "ConferenceRoom"
                    For Each ent In entType.Value
                        Dim conferenceRoom = DirectCast(ent.Entity, ConferenceRoom)
                        conferenceRoom.Stats = GenerateConferenceRoomStats(context2, conferenceRoom.Id)
                    Next
                Case "Reservation"
                    For Each ent In entType.Value
                        Dim reservation = DirectCast(ent.Entity, Reservation)
                        reservation.Stats = GenerateReservationStats(context2, reservation.Id)

                        ''Update ConferenceRoom stats
                        Dim confRoom = Me.Context.ConferenceRooms.Find(reservation.ConferenceRoomId)
                        confRoom.Stats = GenerateConferenceRoomStats(context2, confRoom.Id)
                        AddToSaveMap(newEntitiesMap, confRoom, GetType(ConferenceRoom))

                        ''Update Registration stats
                        Dim registration = Me.Context.Registrations.Find(reservation.RegistrationId)
                        registration.Stats = GenerateRegistrationStats(context2, registration.Id)
                        AddToSaveMap(newEntitiesMap, registration, GetType(Registration))

                    Next

                Case "Registree"  'update  
                    For Each ent In entType.Value
                        Dim registree = DirectCast(ent.Entity, Registree)
                        Dim registration = Me.Context.Registrations.Find(registree.RegistrationId)
                        registration.Stats = GenerateRegistrationStats(context2, registration.Id)
                        AddToSaveMap(newEntitiesMap, registration, GetType(Registration))
                    Next

            End Select
        Next

        context2.SaveChanges()
        For Each ent In newEntitiesMap
            If saveMap.ContainsKey(ent.Key) Then
                'add to existing list
                saveMap(ent.Key).Add(ent.Value)
            Else
                Dim list As New List(Of EntityInfo) From {ent.Value}
                saveMap.Add(ent.Key, list)
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddToSaveMap(AddToSaveMap As Dictionary(Of Type, EntityInfo), entity As Object, classType As Type)
        Dim entInfo = Me.CreateEntityInfo(entity, Breeze.ContextProvider.EntityState.Unchanged)
        AddToSaveMap.Add(classType, entInfo)
    End Sub


    Private Function GenerateConferenceRoomStats(context As Data.Db, conferenceRoomId As Integer) As ConfRoomStats
        Dim confRoom = context.ConferenceRooms.Where(Function(x) x.Id = conferenceRoomId) _
                            .Include(Function(x) x.Reservations.Select(Function(r) r.Occupants)).FirstOrDefault
        confRoom.Stats = confRoom.GenerateStats
        Return confRoom.Stats
    End Function

    Private Function GenerateReservationStats(context As Data.Db, reservationId As Integer) As ReservationStats
        Dim reservation = context.Reservations.Where(Function(x) x.Id = reservationId) _
                            .Include(Function(x) x.Occupants).FirstOrDefault
        reservation.Stats = reservation.GenerateStats
        Return reservation.Stats
    End Function

    Private Function GenerateRegistrationStats(context As Data.Db, registrationId As Integer) As RegStats
        Dim registration = context.Registrations.Where(Function(x) x.Id = registrationId) _
                       .Include(Function(x) x.Registrees.Select(Function(r) r.Person)) _
                       .Include(Function(x) x.Estimates) _
                       .Include(Function(x) x.Reservations.Select(Function(r) r.ConferenceRoom)) _
                       .Include(Function(x) x.Reservations.Select(Function(r) r.Occupants)).FirstOrDefault
        registration.Stats = registration.GenerateStats
        Return registration.Stats
    End Function
```